# Read special chars in an excel using xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I am reading an excel which has Norwegian chars in one of the columns using xlrd, while printing the column values on console it's not printing the actual values.

wb = open_workbook(ip_path+"input.xlsx",encoding_override="cp865")

Eg: Reading ===> abcdefg Lømnopq

Expected Output on console =====> "abcdefg Lømnopq"

But its printing =====>  abcdefg Lr\xf8mnopq

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from the file using the encoding, so you need to decode it when printing. Your print command should look like this:

```
print(cell_value.decode("cp865"))
```

Comment: Still its not working. what should be the data type of cell_value